# Windows API Clear Authentication Tokens

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, authentication

I'm using the [WNetEnumResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all network share connections and [WNetCancelConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385427%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to close them. Then I am using [WNetUseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385482%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to connect to a share using discrete credentials. This process happens multiple times throughout the day.

The problem that I'm running into is that after the first flow through the process I'm getting:

> System Error 1219 has occurred.
>
> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
>   using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
>   previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

This happens even when the enumeration says there are no current connections.

My question is: why? Why am I getting this error? Is the authenticated connection to the server still cached? Can I enumerate these authentication tokens? Kerberos? LSA?

I haven't been able to find the smallest foothold of information to progress forward on this project. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I am seeing similar issues with anonymous samba connections that need to 'upgrade' to a valid user when viewing specify directories.

Comment: Oh gosh, we faced this a few years ago... There *is* a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to remember the solution we used when we came across this problem for a network backup program a few years ago.

I'm certain the solution involves using either `WNetAddConnection2` or `WNetAddConnection3` instead of `WNetUseConnection`. I think that passing the flag `CONNECT_CRED_RESET` should take care of this, but I'm not absolutely certain.

Note that `CONNECT_CRED_RESET` is only documented for `WNetAddConnection2` and not `WNetAddConnection3`, though MSDN says the only difference between the two is the `hWnd` parameter for owner of dialog windows - I'd try with `WNetAddConnection2` and only if it works, experiment with `WNetAddConnection3`. You may even get it to work with `WNetUseConnection`!

Make sure to [note the dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `CONNECT_CRED_RESET` has on other flags.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to work for me, those flags are meant for command-line applications and actually request input from the user. I'm trying to finish off a GUI application for desktop users so there is no interaction with the CLI.

Comment: @joshperry I meant to try to reset the connections first w/ `CONNECT_CRED_RESET` then establish the connection your way once the creds are gone.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not true, you need to read the documentation that you linked me to. `CONNECT_CRED_RESET`: "This flag is also ignored unless you set the CONNECT_COMMANDLINE flag." `CONNECT_COMMANDLINE`: "If this flag is set, the operating system prompts the user for authentication using the command line instead of a graphical user interface (GUI). This flag is ignored unless CONNECT_INTERACTIVE is also set." `CONNECT_INTERACTIVE`: "If this flag is set, the operating system may interact with the user for authentication purposes." Like I said, this provides zero help in my use-case.

Comment: @joshperry I'll do some more digging and get back to you.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi are there any ultimate solutions for this?