# Why WNetAddConnection2 still returns 1219 after successfully calling WNetCancelConnection2?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

I wrote some code to connect with some share on a remote server. If `WNetAddConnection2` returns `ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT` (1219), I will first cancel the connection by `WNetCancelConnection2` (return NO_ERROR). And then reconnect. But `WNetAddConnection2` still returns `1219`. 
Why this and how to fix it?

Here's my code

```
BOOL ADDirectorySearch::IPCConnect(CString strServerName, CString strDomainName, CString strUserName, CString strPassWord)
{
    CString strServerNameWithSlash = _T("\\\\") + strServerName; //actually is \\klbnt
    CString strFullUserName = strDomainName + _T("\\") + strUserName; //is domaintest\administrator
    _bstr_t bstrServerNameWithSlash = strServerNameWithSlash;
    _bstr_t bstrFullUserName = strFullUserName;
    _bstr_t bstrPassWord = strPassWord;
    DWORD dwResult;
    NETRESOURCEW netResource;
    memset(&netResource, 0, sizeof(netResource));
    netResource.dwScope = RESOURCE_GLOBALNET;  
    netResource.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    netResource.dwDisplayType = RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC;  
    netResource.dwUsage = RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE;
    netResource.lpProvider = L"";
    netResource.lpRemoteName = bstrServerNameWithSlash;//Remote IP like:\\192.168.1.11
    dwResult = WNetAddConnection2W(&netResource, bstrPassWord, bstrFullUserName, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE);
    if (dwResult == ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT)
    {
        dwResult = WNetCancelConnection2W(bstrServerNameWithSlash, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, TRUE);
        if (dwResult == NO_ERROR)
        {
            dwResult = WNetAddConnection2W(&netResource, bstrPassWord, bstrFullUserName, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE);
        }
        else
        {
            //MyMessageBox_Error(_T("IPCConnect Error."), _T("Error"));
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    if (dwResult == NO_ERROR)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        //MyMessageBox_Error(_T("IPCConnect Error."), _T("Error"));
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

FYI: After typing "net use" in cmd, I got this, I feel there's something with error:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\klbnt\NRDC1001          Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: You didn't set resource.lpLocalName.  No WNetCancelConnection2() visible in the snippet.

Comment: You might need to specify the share name as well as the server name in WNetCancelConnection2, i.e., `\\klbnt\NRDC1001` instead of just `\\klbnt`.

Comment: I set lpLocalName to "" but nothing changed. WNetCancelConnection2 is called between 2 WNetAddConnection2 calls within my code. Also what's the relationship between connecting with \\klbnt and \\klbnt\nrdc1001? Does a connection with \\klbnt implicitly includes the connections with all klbnt's shares? or there's nothing with each other? I just wanna grant permissions to my process for accessing remote's shares, so what's the right way to do this？

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows API Clear Authentication Tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673194/windows-api-clear-authentication-tokens)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just having this problem now, and basically it seemed that it was due to another process still having file open, *even though* I specified `"true"` as the last parameter of `WNetCancelConnection2()` to force close the connection. Once I shut-down that other process, I was able to use successfully switch between credentials connecting and re-connecting to the same share. This is on Windows 2012 (64-bit), and the share was local (referenced by the machinename).

BUT...it's still a problem if you want to connect to different shares on the same machine. If I try to connect to `\\mymachine\share1` as `user1` then to `\\mymachine\share2` as `user2`, I get the 1219 error (even if it's in a completely different process). I have to explicitly call `WNetCancelConnnection` on `\\mymachine\share1` before I can connect to `share2`, which means at the point you connect to a share on a particular machine, you may have to first enumerate existing connections and close each one.

Rather frustrating, and I can't understand the design principle here. It seems the flags to create temporary connections etc. have no effect on this behaviour either. Really what I want to be able to do is say "for this thread, connect to this share on this machine and as this user, such that all attempts to access files on the share are done with that user's credentials". That way what other processes/threads are doing can't cause issues with the current one.

Comment: It should be possible to use `LogonUserEx` with `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` to get a separate logon session for connecting to the remote server.  However, I'm not sure whether impersonation will work or whether you'd need to launch an actual subprocess with the new token and do the work from there.

Comment: I originally started with using impersonation, but it made trying to access all the other resources I needed (e.g. databases) a real PITA!

Comment: Impersonation can be turned on and off as needed, so this shouldn't really be a problem.  One approach would be to map a drive letter to the share, once the drive letter is mapped you might be able to turn impersonating off and still use the drive letter.

Comment: In my case I just have to know whether any active connections are not. I used the WMI Namespace `MSFT_SmbConnection`. Which is capable of showing the active SMB connections even after the WNetCancelConnection2. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/smb/msft-smbconnection

The powershell cmdlet **Get-SmbConnection** also show the active connections.